# React router same path with other query Param

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is it possible with react-router to change the route if the queryParam changes but the path stays the same?
I have defined two routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={List} />
    <Route path="/=" component={Content} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

My List view basically shows a list of items. When someone clicks on the item the url should be changed to `/?content=content-id`.

The final application should have the following routes:

```
"/" => render List View
"?content=content-id" => render Content View
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not at the router level, but you can easily use the params within the loaded component to choose what to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can do the following

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={List} />
    <Route path="/:id=" component={Content} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

in the  Contect.js:

```
let { id } = useParams();//if it's func component
```

Or

```
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/template',
      search: '?query=abc',
      state: { detail: response.data }
<Link to={{
      pathname: '/template',
      search: '?query=abc',
      state: { detail: response.data }
    }}> My Link </Link>
})
```

in the second way you can do a query and send state with it.